# To Have An ID or Not To Have An ID - Regarding Value Object

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's say two domain objects: Product and ProductVariety (with data such as color, size etc). The relationship between these two is one-to-many. Conceptually saying in the domain driven design, the ProductVariaty should be a value object, which is not the same object once its data is changed. From the implementation point of view, however, it is better to have some sort identification for the ProductVariaty so that we know which ProductVariety is selected and so on. Is an only solution to convert it to an entity class?

The following is a code segment to illustrate this situation.

```
@Embeddable
class ProductVariety {...}

@Entity
class Product {

  @ElementCollection
  private Set<ProductVariety> varities;

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Conceptually saying in the domain driven design, the ProductVariaty should be a value object, which is not the same object once its data is changed

That's not *quite* the right spelling.  In almost all cases (many nines), Value Object should be immutable; its data never changes.

> Is an only solution to convert it to an entity class?

"It depends".

There's nothing conceptually wrong with having an identifier be part of the immutable state of the object.  For example, [PANTONE 5395 C](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/5395-C) is an `Identifier` (value type) that is unique to a particular `Color` (value type).

However, for an identifier like `PANTONE 5395 C` to have value, it needs to be semantically stable.  Changing the mapping of the identifier to the actual color spectrum elements destroys the meaning of previous messages about color.  If the identifier is "wrong", then the proper thing to do is deprecate the identifier and nominate a replacement.

Put simply, you can't repaint the house by taking the label off the old paint can and putting it on a new one.

In that case, there's no great advantage to using the identifier vs the entire value object.  But its not wrong to do so, either.

On the other hand, if you are really modeling a *mapping*, and you want to follow changes that happen over time -- that's pretty much the definition of an entity right there.

What it really depends on is "cost to the business".  What are the trade offs involved, within the context of the problem you are trying to solve?

Note: if you really do find yourself in circumstances where you are considering something like this, be sure to *document* your cost benefit analysis, so that the next developer that comes along has a trail of breadcrumbs to work from.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Immutable is another characteristic of the ProductVariety object. I am going to add an ID field in the UUID data type to the class.